# How do i make my text stop overflowing and break down into smaller sentences

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am currently working on the text a user will post if they make a status update to their code. However, anytime I add long text, it overflows rather than creates a new line. How do i make it stop overflowing and make a new line after it has reached a certain limit?

Here is my code in question:

```
<div id="text-container" style={{position: 'absolute', top: '30%', left: '5%', backgroundColor: '#FFFBEE', height: '30%', width: '90%', borderRadius: '16px', overflow: 'hidden'}}><p style={{maxWidth: '20ch', whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>{state.posts[i].text}</p></div>
```

Here is what my issue looks like via an image:

[image]

Comment: remove `whiteSpace: 'nowrap'`

Comment: it didnt do anything ^

Comment: It's because you have `overflow: 'hidden'`.

Comment: now it flows past the yellow box

Comment: I think the issue is that the text has no white spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your styles include `white-space: nowrap` which forbids any text to wrap into new lines. Remove it.

Removing it will leave you with the more practical [`white-space: normal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

> normal
>
> Sequences of white space are collapsed. Newline characters in the source are handled the same as other white space. Lines are broken as necessary to fill line boxes.

In your example, you wont see a difference, because your test is one single long word, which does not break in the `normal` behaviour.

If your users are not Germans typing long words like Donaudampfschiffartsgesellschaftskapitänsversicherungsgesellschaft, you should be fine.

If they are, you have different possibilities.

### Wrap long words

```css
section {
  border: 1px gray dashed;
  padding: .5em;
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<section lang="de">
  <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word">Donaudampfschiffartsgesellschaftskapitänsversicherungsgesellschaft</p>
  <p style="hyphens: auto">Donaudampfschiffartsgesellschaftskapitänsversicherungsgesellschaft</p>
</section>
```

The first line is using [the `overflow-wrap` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) set to `word-wrap`, which “…will only create a break if an entire word cannot be placed on its own line without overflowing”.

This is often used for wrapping email addresses or URLs

The second one is using [the `hyphens` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens) to apply orthographic rules to separate words based on language (notice the `lang="de"` attribute). It depends on a dictionary, though. So it only works in your browser if the dictionary is installed.

For me, it looks like this:

[image: The mentioned very long word, separated neatly into the outlining border, with hyphens at the end of the lines, which break where a dictionary allows it]

### Do not fix a containers height

As @Johannes realised, you are also fixing the text container’s height. You never should to that with a container for text. Let it flow, and use `height: auto` which is the default.

If you do want to enforce a certain minimum height, you can do so by applying [`min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)

Answer (score 2):

Your example is completely unrealistic. Use real language, which consists of words with spaces in between, and the text will break normally once `whiteSpace: 'nowrap` is removed. To have the background-color cover the whole text, change the outer boxes `height` to `min-height` (on `#text-container`).

Here I edited your code to fit regular HTML, inserted some example text, removed the white-space setting and changed the outer boxes `height` to `min-height`:

```html
<div id="text-container" style="position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 5%; background-color:#FFFBEE; min-height:30%; width: 90%; border-radius: 16px;"><p style="max-width:20ch;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. </p></div>
```

For some reason your inner box (the `p` element) is much narrower than the outer box so there's a lot of empty space to the right. If you don't want that, erase the `max-width:20ch´ from the` p`tag.

Comment: Still doesnt work, now the text just goes past the yellow box

Comment: I added something to my answer, should work as expected now.